# Dynamic libraries; how to fix useless dependencies?

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of Dll's in my project, using VStudio 9.0 compiler, pre-compiled headers are used for all my Dll's. The dll's loading process is done by implicit caller (.dll, .lib and header must be supplied).

I typically create a different macro definition file per dll, for instance if my current Dll is called MYMacroDll I add a file **_MyMacroDll.h** which contains:

```
#ifndef _MYMACRODLL_H_
#define _MYMACRODLL_H_

#ifdef _WIN32

#ifdef MYMACRODLL_EXPORTS
    #define MYMACRODLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MYMACRODLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define MYMACRODLL_CALL __cdecl

#else

    #define MYMACRODLL_API
    #define MYMACRODLL_CALL

#endif

#endif
```

I know the code can be simplified but I keep the last defines for portability, at least, that's what I understood...

The pre-compiled header file **pch.h**, will always include the macro definition file **_MyMacroDll.h**, this makes things easier to me, 'cause later I can decide whether a new class or function will be interfaced or not. This so far works correct.

The confusion comes from using the dll interfaces in another dll; let's suppose a second dll **ImageLoaderDll**. This one uses instances or references of one (or several) of the interfaced classes/functions in _MyMacroDll. At first glance I guessed there was no need of including the _MyMacroDll.h, but when compiling the ImageLoaderDll it complains with

```
error C2470: '_AnInterfaceClassFromMyMacro' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
```

Then I have to include the _MyMacroDll.h in the pre-compiler header file of the other Dll, my project is becoming really messy and I find more and more useless dependencies.
What am doing wrong? Is there another way of setting up the macro definitions so I can avoid adding it to the client Dll's? Am not an expert regarding software design, but in this situation the more decoupled the better.
Hope my explanation was good enough.

Comment: In what way do you view your project as becoming messy?  Are you concerned that you are exporting MyMacro stuff from another DLL?  Or are you concerned that you need to `#include` stuff in one DLL from another DLL even if you don't need to use it?

Comment: Definitely am concerned about the need to #include stuff I don't need... but the worse, is to create a chain dependency Dll1 uses Dll2, then Dll3 uses interfaces from Dll2, but it will also need Dll1 header files. Maybe this is the way it should be, it bothers me the fact I use third party libraries, can't recall any scenario where I need to include such macro things, that's probably because is declared inside their pre-compiled headers or somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DLL interface from MyMacroDll in ImageLoaderDll, then you **do** have a dependency. `ImageLoaderDll` should include `_MyMacroDll.h`, otherwise you can't call its functions correctly. It's exactly the same as including `<string.h>` when you want to call `strlen`.